# Set value after unpublishing content

Tags: 8, rules

I'm using drupal 8 and the scheduler module to automatically unpublish custom content after x days have passed.

While unpublishing a boolean field from the custom content needs to be enabled/disabled.

So far I tried rules module *after_a_node_has_been_unpublished_by_scheduler with Condition: Entity has field* with *Action: Set a data value* Unfortunatelly the action does nothing.

What else could I try?

Comment: are you specifically looking for a non-code based solution (like rules)? Because if you are comfortable coding you should be able to do this with a simple hook_node_update implementation since the node is saved at the time it is (un)published with scheduler

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I used hook_node_presave because hook_node_update did not save the change. I've isolated the unpublished node by testing for `$node->original->get('status')->value` and `$node->get('status')->value`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create your custom code in a hook_cron, and you can handle your verifications following the date of publication.

Comment: I would not use this solution. You are creating a situation where the scheduled state change and the boolean field change the poster is looking to make are completely decoupled. This can cause one to happen without the other in a specific cron run